# Cant invoke Calculate method from EPPlus using C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a cell with a formula, that I need to invoke Calculate() method on, to get the result.

Somehow I cannet invoke the Calculate method on any cells in my sheet, what am I missing?

I am using EPPlus version 4.0.5.0.
My code is as follows:

```
ws2.Cells[failedRow, failedColumn + 1].Formula = "SUM(B20:B" + (failedRow - 1) + ")";
```

And I need Calculate on that same cell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revising my answer based on @Stewart mentioning the Formula Calculations they added.

I tried again and it DOES seem to work.  So, Jesper, in you case, `cell.Calculate()` should do it for you.   I tried this:

```
    public void Formula_Calc_Test()
    {
        var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
        datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[] {new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int))});

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var row = datatable.NewRow();
            row[0] = i;
            row[1] = i * 10;
            datatable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var workbook = pck.Workbook;
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            var cells = worksheet.Cells;

            cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

            var failedRow = 11;
            cells["C1"].Formula = "SUM(B2:B" + (failedRow - 1) + ")";
            cells["C1"].Calculate();
            Console.WriteLine(cells["C1"].Value);

        }
    }
```

And did get `360` in the output.

Comment: Hi Ernie, I think they INTEND to support it in the most recent versions (see this article https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20Formula%20calculation ) That said, I cannot get it working as I'd expect (nor even if my expectations are the indended functionality!). not sure if they have a bug reported for it - it's easy enough for me to work around for now

Comment: @Stewart_R Yep, you are correct!  I should have qualified my answer better.  I have tried using calculation as well but it seemed to have no effect.  I debugged it once but cant remember why I dismissed it.  It would be handy to have indeed but seems like a VERY complex and risky thing to do so I am surprised they even tried.

Comment: Hi Ernie. Thank you very much for your input. Tried out your example, and it did work. Did a little investigation on my own code, and somehow I had forgot to include the namespace. Was writing the specific namespace when invoking new OfficeXml components, instead of using the directive. Embarrising mistake, but it works now. Tyvm! :-) Cant upvote, since I do not have enough rep. yet...

Comment: @JesperNielsen No problem.  Just make the question as answered which will help you get some points.

Answer (score 1):

[XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/XlsIO) is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel 2003/2007/2010/2013/2016 files. Using [XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/XlsIO), you can calculated the formula of the cell very easily. The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Step 1: Create a console application
Step 2: Add reference to Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base and Syncfusion.Compression.Base; You can add these reference to your project using NuGet also.
Step 3: Copy & paste the following code snippet.

The following code snippet illustrates how to calculate the formula value in the cell using XlsIO

```
using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
{
  IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

  application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

  IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);

  IWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

  //Setting values to the cells

  sheet.Range["A1"].Number = 10;

  sheet.Range["B1"].Number = 10;

  //Setting formula in the cell

  sheet.Range["C1"].Formula = "=SUM(A1,B1)";

  // Enabling CalcEngine for computing the formula
  sheet.EnableSheetCalculations();

  string computedValue = sheet.Range["C1"].CalculatedValue;

  workbook.SaveAs("Formula.xlsx");

  // Disabling the CalcEngine
  sheet.DisableSheetCalculations();
}
```

For further information about XlsIO, please refer our [help documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/overview)

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Thats another work around, but I think i'll stick to EPPlus. But thank you for your input.

Comment: @JesperNielsen -  Thank you for your feedback